# Databricks cluster Stages are not starting

Tags: apache-spark, hive, bigdata, query-optimization, azure-databricks

```
spark.sql(
          s"""
select
nb.*,
facl_bed.hsid as facl_decn_bed_hsid,
facl_bed.bed_day_decn_seq_nbr as facl_decn_bednbr,
case when facl_bed.hsid is not null then concat(substr(nb.cse_dt, 1, 10), ' 00:00:00.000') else cast(null as string) end as en_dt
from nobed nb
left outer join decn_bed_interim facl_bed on
(nb.hsid=facl_bed.hsid and nb.facl_decn_hsid=facl_bed.hsid)
where nb.facl_decn_hsc_id is not null
union all
select
nb.*,
cast(null as int) as facl_decn_bed_hsid,
cast(null as int) as facl_decn_bednbr,
cast(null as string) as en_dt
from nobed nb
where nb.facl_decn_hsid is null
""")
```

I was executing the above snippet on databricks spark cluster. I was taking so much of time to complete the task.
here My tables are having very large data.

From my DAG I can see it is taking much in union all.
[image]
Here Stage 205 and 206 are taking so much of time to complete.

[image]

What could be the reason for this and how can I solve this?